# How to loop the Rain Animation for 10 minute video?

Tags: animation, particles

I have searched for many hours, and found some videos using **Geometry Node** for the Infinite Animation of Rain, but is there a way for **Particle System** ?

For example: I created a rain with a **start frame** of -200 and **end frame** of 200, now I want to repeat from frame 0-100 forever. Is there a way to do it without **Make Instances Real** ??

I want something like "Repeat Action", "Repeat Disk Cache" or something like that

Comment: AFAIK you can't.

Comment: The problem with _Make Instances Real_ is that this will only create those particle objects which exist on the frame you are currently on and in the current location, without animation. The only possible solution I see is using the external addon "Cake Particles" which you can get here: [Cake Particles at Gumroad](https://scaryplasmon.gumroad.com/l/CakeParticles). On the site it says there is a version 2.5, however when I try to install it it's not there, so I use 2.1.2 instead (works in Blender 4.0.2 as well although not stated there). With this you get the particles as keyframed objects.

Comment: It sounds like something that can help me. Thanks, Let's me check it